# Redirection and HTTPS

Tags: redirects, dns, https

Hoping it's a stupid and basic question, but can't find the answer in Google, nor in search here.

Website setup:

http://www.example.com

http://sub.example.com

Then introduced SSL, so now it's:

https://www.example.com

https://sub.example.com

Have shared hosting with a cPanel (if it's relevant info) and using Cloudflare free package.

1)
How can I make users typing:

example.com, and www.example.com
be directly redirected (without several redirects) to
https://www.example.com

2)
Can I also make the following, for users typing:

sub.example.com **as well as** www.sub.example.com  to be redirected to:
https://sub.example.com

I have made it to work, but it took using two pagerules in CloudFlare. Is there a more clever and better solution?

What I've done so far:

DNS:

A mydomain.com points to hostIP

A sub points to hostIP

CNAME www alias of mydomain

CNAME www.sub alias of sub.mydomain.com

This alone didn't help, so I had to make two page rules in CloudFlare, in order:

www.sub.example.com/*  - forwarding url 301 to https://sub.example.com/$1

example.com/*  - forwarding url 301 to https://www.example.com/$1

I also set "Always use HTTPS" in CloudFlare Crypto settings.

Only total of 3 page rules with CloudFlare, one used to not cache admin when logged in. So a total of 2 to left to work with. Although I **guess** there is a better way to do it, is there?

From what I gather, setting it up in .htaccess is no longer considered a good policy, is it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry but we already have a range of questions and answers regarding non-ssl to ssl, including subdomains to main domain. Please use the search feature and visit our help centre for further assitance.

Comment: You can also find help regarding page rules redirects using cloudflare, for example `http://example.com/*` > `https://www.example.com/$1`, `https://example.com/*` > `https://www.example.com/$1`, `https://sub-domain.example.com/*` > `https://www.example.com/$1`. If your limited by page rules, upgrade, since minor page redirects like these are best handled by Cloudflare because of its one less server-side request or handle just the sub domain by the htaccess.

Comment: That's sort of the answer I was looking for - better off using cloudflare than configuring things server-side? 
In that case I'm set - since I've only managed to make it work using cloudflare. :)
Thanks.

P.S. Having trouble finding the straight answer with google, or this community. Didn't see it answered before, that's why I posted the question.